# Syncing a File Through iCloud in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I am trying to give my iOS app the capability to sync the user's data via iCloud. I Figured the way to go was to use iCloud Documents, as I already save/load a json file locally to store their data. However, I'm having trouble getting it working. I tried numerous tutorials online and none of them worked. Additionally, I cannot have the file visible to the user in their documents.
My latest code is based off [this](https://theswiftdev.com/how-to-use-icloud-drive-documents/) tutorial. Here is my current code, in my viewDidLoad:

```
    // check for container existence
    if let url = self.containerUrl, !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path, isDirectory: nil) {
        print("does not exist")
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    let documentUrl = self.containerUrl!.appendingPathComponent("test.txt")
    print("url: \(documentUrl)")
    
    let string = "Hello World!"
    
    do {
        //try string.write(to: documentUrl, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        print("saved")
        try print("Data: \(String(contentsOf: documentUrl))")
    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

I switch uncommenting the save and load lines for testing on different devices.

And here's what I added to my info.plist:

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
<dict>
    <key>iCloud.testCloudStorage</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
        <string>testCloudStorage</string>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
        <string>Any</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

and here's my capabilities section:
[image: My capabilities section in Xcode]

So far, I am able to read and write to the file fine on one device, but on another device also signed in with my iCloud account, I get a file not found error:

```
The file “test.txt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

I can see the file in my iCloud Drive (which I don't want) on both devices, but I can only read it on the one I saved it with.

Any help or working tutorials on this subject would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you added, "iCloud Containers to your App ID"? The container's name is red so there can be a problem with sync caused by this error.

Comment: Actually, when I quit Xcode and opened the project again, the name is no longer red. Where would I add the "iCloud Containers to your App ID"? I didn't see anything under the capabilities section...

Comment: check this thread https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651070

Comment: I checked and the iCloud Containers that I created through Xcode appear in the list of cloud containers on the developer page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quit and re-open Xcode and build it again.